# map over nested object in an array

Tags: reactjs, arrays, object

Currently trying to map over an array that has multiple nested objects.  When I run the map function, it only returns the outer object.

[image]

```
const [moreDetails, setMoreDetails] = useState([]);
const [details, setDetails] = useState("");

const handleAddMoreDetails = () => {
  setMoreDetails((prevState) => [
    {
      ...prevState,
      details: details
    }
  ]);
  setDetails("");
};

return (
  <div className="App">
    <input
      type="text"
      value={details}
      onChange={(e) => setDetails(e.target.value)}
    />

    <button onClick={handleAddMoreDetails}>Add Detail</button>

    {moreDetails &&
      moreDetails.map((item, index) => <p key={index}>{item.details}</p>)}
  </div>
);
```

This is similar to what I am trying to accomplish. I would like for it to render all of them when added.  I am thinking it may be the one I am trying to add a new detail

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-bash-sz4vqd?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Do you want to iterate over objects as well ?

Comment: yes,  i was trying to render the data from the objects

Comment: What is `item` in each iteration? Is it really an object as you claim? If it is an object, what are its keys? Are they what you expect? The screenshot of the structure of `moreDetails` doesn't seem to match what you think it is and you need to figure out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't in the rendering, it's in the state update:

```
setMoreDetails((prevState) => [
  {
    ...prevState,
    details: details
  }
]);
```

If `prevState` was an array, for example:

```
[
  { details: 'first record' }
]
```

Then what happens after your state update?  This update is creating an array with *one object*, which contains both the previous array and the new object.  So the new result is:

```
[
  {
    0: {
      details: 'first record'
    },
    details: 'second record'
  }
]
```

Each update to the state will continue to create an array with one object, nesting the previous array inside that object.

Instead, create an array containing the elements of the previous array plus the one new object:

```
setMoreDetails((prevState) => [
  ...prevState,
  {
    details: details
  }
]);
```

So the new state would be:

```
[
  { details: 'first record' },
  { details: 'second record' }
]
```

Comment: its a single array with nested objects.  I tried flat(), but that didn't work

Comment: @arod1207: Can you perhaps replicate this in a runnable [mcve]?  It doesn't need to be a full React app.  If the problem is simply mapping over a data structure then you can manually create the data structure and map over it, doing nothing more than logging a result to the console.  That example can demonstrate what specifically isn't working as expected.

Comment: Just updated question with codesandbox link.  You can see how my objects become nested in the array.

Comment: @arod1207: I've udpated the answer.  The problem wasn't in mapping over the structure, the problem was in how you were creating/updating the structure.

Comment: Such a bonehead mistake on my part.  You are exactly right.  Thank you so much for the help and explanation